# Query Optimisation (ORDER BY)

Tags: sql, oracle10g, performance, sql-order-by

I have an SQL query similar to below:

```
SELECT NAME,
       MY_FUNCTION(NAME) -- carries out some string manipulation
  FROM TITLES
  ORDER BY NAME; -- has an index.
```

The TITLES table has approximately 12,000 records. At the moment the query takes over 5 minutes to execute but if I remove the ORDER BY clause then it executes within a couple of seconds.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to be speed up this query.

Comment: You say "similar to".  In what ways is the real query different - does it join several tables (or is it based on a view that does?)  Does it actually select many other columns from the table as well?

Comment: Also, when you say that without the ORDER BY it executes in a couple of seconds, is that to return ALL the data or just the first N rows to be displayed?

Comment: @PeteDaMeat, have you compared the query plans of the two queries?

Comment: When I say "similar to" I mean that although the query above is not exactly the same as the query I am working on, the above query does replicate the same issue.

Comment: It currently take 2 seconds to return N rows without the ORDER BY.

Comment: @PeteDaMeat, how long does it take to return **all** the data, without the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @PeteDaMeat, see my new answer regarding "first N rows" processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the EXPLAIN statement to see where the issue is

```
EXPLAIN SELECT NAME, MY_FUNCTION(NAME) FROM TITLES ORDER BY NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

If MY_FUNCTION is deterministic (i.e. always returns the same result for the same input value) then you could create an index on (NAME, MY_FUNCTION(NAME)) and it may help (or may not!)

Comment: I don't see why an index on (NAME, MY_FUNCTION(NAME)) could ever help his/her query. :(

Comment: Because the query could be answered by reading the index alone, not the table - and the index is already in NAME order.

Comment: Suppose the function is not deterministic.  Better yet, what if it is but the inner workings change and the function returns different values than when the index was first created. What would happen?  Would the results of a query differ if the index was used vs if the table was hit directly?

Answer (score 1):

In comments under the question, you say that it takes 2 seconds "to return N rows without the ORDER BY". That makes sense: without the ORDER BY you will just get the first N rows encountered, as soon as they are encountered. With the ORDER BY, the first N rows are returned only **after** the results have been sorted into the correct order.

If the query is being used in a situation where getting the first N rows fast is important (e.g. an online report with pagination) then you could try adding a FIRST_ROWS or FIRST_ROWS_*n* hint to the query, to try to persuade it to use the index.  See [Choosing an Optimizer Goal](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/optimops.htm#i38318)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds weird. What's `name` column type?

Have you checked for defective hardware errors? Maybe (just maybe) your query with the `order by` clause is using your index, and your index is located in a defective disk (it could be in a different disk from the table if they are located in different tablespaces).

Comment: Not very weird.  The ORDER BY is probably causing a SORT to be performed on all the data before it is returned.

Comment: Agree. But `ORDER BY` could use index on `name` he/she is claiming to have to avoid sorting. Besides, sorting 12000 records shouldn't take more than a couple of seconds. And apparently is taking 5 minutes!

Comment: True, 5 minutes is a very long time for 12000 rows